# where is my CD/DVD drive?

Tags: filemanager

I have tried half a dozen file managers trying to find one that's usable for a same person, and have not yet seen one that recognized the DVD drive on my dual-boot (orig Win7) machine.

Comment: The question is not clear. What happens when you insert a audio CD or DVD? what happens when you insert a data CD? Please provide more details in the question. Your CD/DVD drive is probably in NJ.

Answer (score 3):

If you insert a CD or DVD, it should be automatically detected and will appear as a removable media drive in the nautilus file browser, otherwise it will be hidden.

You can confirm that the CD drive is recognised by running the following command in a terminal and looking for your CD drive in the results:

```
sudo lshw -class disk
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CD/DVD drive is always recognized. However,you will not find a icon for it unless you have mounted any CD/DVD. Once you mount a CD/DVD,you can find it in `/media/DISC_NAME`.